# Vuex Laravel Loads all data

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I've been trying to load all of my data when the time I log in. Currently, I've only managed to display data through the console through vuex file. I just want to achieve this because wherever it loads all data when login, it will easier for me to call every function on every page.

I think the first step is to display it on vue devtools?

*This is what I've tried*.
I have this file on my "./store/modules/currentUser.js"

```
import axios from "axios";
const state = {
};
const getters = {};
const actions = {
    loadEmployee({}){
        axios.post(BASE_URL + '/transportation/driver/autoComplete').then(response => {
            console.log(response.data); // how to pass result to devtools?
        });
    }
};
const mutations = {};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations

}
```

*Login.vue*

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            listdata:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$store.dispatch('currentUser/loadEmployee', this.listdata);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my vuedevtools looks like

[image]

And I want to fetch all data on listdata array vue devtools

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vuex, you should probably load state in dev tools.

[image]

However, your issue is caused by not having a mutation, so you never update the state.

```
import axios from "axios";
const state = {
    transansportDrivers: [] 
};
const getters = {};
const actions = {
    loadEmployee({}){
        axios.post(BASE_URL + '/transportation/driver/autoComplete').then(response => {
            commit('setTransportDrivers', response.data)
        });
    }
};
const mutations = {
    setTransportDrivers: (state, drivers) => {
        state.transansportDrivers= drivers;
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, should I use mutations? instead of actions? Honestly, I'm a newbie in vuex

Comment: You should definitely use both. I just realized that you're having your issue because you don't have a mutation. I'll update my comment

Comment: thank you for the solution, but one thing how can I call the result or display the dev tools function load employee() ?

Comment: You should create a new question because without your code showing how you're doing it currently, it's had to say. If this questions is resolved or you find my question useful, feel free to upvote it or mark it as a solution.

Comment: Yes it is useful, but I've been wondering through you code above how can know if  I pass data to the vue file ?